# Keep getting access violation when trying to access array

Tags: arrays, delphi, dynamic, access-violation

I'm rather new to delphi, and I keep getting access violations when I try to access my array "nieuwButtons". Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
unit UGeneral;

  interface

  uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
    System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
    Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids, SMDBGrid,
    KJSMDBGrid, Vcl.ExtCtrls, KJPanel, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Mask, Vcl.DBCtrls,
    Data.DB;

  type
    TGeneral = class(TObject)

    private
      { Private declarations }

    public
      nieuwButtons: array of TButton;
      nieuwButtonsDataSource: array of TDataSource;

      procedure listEdits(x, y: Integer; owner: TComponent; parent: TWinControl;
        source: TDataSource);
      procedure nieuwClick(Sender: TObject);
      { Public declarations }
    end;

  var
    General: TGeneral;

  implementation

  procedure TGeneral.nieuwClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
    i: Integer;

  begin
    for i := 0 to Length(nieuwButtons) - 1 do
    begin
      if (nieuwButtons[i] = Sender) then
      begin
        nieuwButtonsDataSource[i].DataSet.Insert;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure TGeneral.listEdits(x, y: Integer; owner: TComponent;
    parent: TWinControl; source: TDataSource);
  var
    i: Integer;
    edit: TDBEdit;
    _label: TLabel;
    biggestWidth: Integer;
    button: TButton;
    edits: array of TDBEdit;
    index: Integer;
  begin
    if nieuwButtons <> nil then //I get an access violation here
    begin
      SetLength(General.nieuwButtons, 0);
      SetLength(nieuwButtonsDataSource, 0);
    end;
    index := Length(nieuwButtons);
    SetLength(nieuwButtons, index + 1);
    SetLength(nieuwButtonsDataSource, index + 1);
    button := TButton.Create(owner);
    button.parent := parent;
    button.Top := y;
    button.Left := x;
    button.Caption := 'Nieuw';
    button.OnClick := nieuwClick;

    nieuwButtons[index] := button;
    nieuwButtonsDataSource[index] := source;

    biggestWidth := 0;
    SetLength(edits, source.DataSet.Fields.Count);
    edit := TDBEdit.Create(owner);
    for i := 0 to source.DataSet.Fields.Count - 1 do
    begin
      _label := TLabel.Create(owner);
      _label.parent := parent;
      _label.Caption := source.DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName;
      _label.Top := ((i * 22) + 30 + y); // 22 = standaard(?) hoogte van edittext
      _label.Left := x;

      _label.Show;

      if _label.Width > biggestWidth then
      begin
        biggestWidth := _label.Width;
      end;
    end;
    i := 0;
    for i := 0 to source.DataSet.Fields.Count - 1 do
    begin
      edit := TDBEdit.Create(owner);
      edit.parent := parent;
      edit.DataField := source.DataSet.Fields[i].FieldName;
      edit.DataSource := source;
      edit.Top := ((i * edit.Height) + 30 + y);
      edit.Left := biggestWidth + 30;
      edits[i] := edit;
      edit.Show;
    end;

  end;

end.
```

Comment: Assigned throws an access violation too :/

Comment: The location suggests that `Self` is `nil`. Show how you call `listEdits`.

Comment: General.listEdits(0, 0, Self, KJPanel4, DataModule2.bestemmingSource);

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It won't be the call to the method, rather the instantiation of the instance

Comment: You should use for i := low(nieuwButtons) to high(nieuwButtons) instead of for i := 0 to Length(nieuwButtons) - 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way for that line of code to raise an exception is if the instance of `TGeneral` is not valid.

The error will be found in the code that instantiates the class. Common forms of this error are:

1. Forgetting to instantiate the object at all.
2. Instantiating the object incorrectly by calling the constructor on the uninitialized instance rather than the type.

To illustrate the latter fault, it looks like this:

```
var
  General: TGeneral;
....
General.Create; // sometimes this way
General := General.Create; // or sometimes this way
```

But the correct way is like this:

```
General := TGeneral.Create;
```

Comment: Thank you! This resolved it. I find it weird how I am even able to call the functions inside general when the object hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: Here `General` is really nothing more than a pointer. When you write `General.DoSomething(42)` what actually happens is that the subject of the method call `General` is passed as an extra implicit parameter. So it's really `TGeneral.DoSomething(General, 42)`. Now, if `General` has not been initialized to point to a valid instance, the call is fine, but inside the object when you try to refer to `Self` then you typically encounter runtime errors.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Didn't know it worked that way, only been programming in delphi for 2 days so far. I'll mark your answer as the solution in a minute.